# Allow user via FTP to edit, delete & create files in specific folder

Tags: server, permissions, ftp, vsftpd

I'm trying to use `vsftpd` to create a FTP server on my ubuntu machine.

I'm also using apache2 to host websites.

How can I setup `vsftpd` to connect a specific user directly to the `/var/www/<websitename>/public_html` folder?

Example:
I want user `trinity` to connect to ftp and instantly get directed to the `/var/www/trinityplay.net/public_html` folder. The user is supposed to be able to create, edit and delete files within that folder.

While user `walle` is supposed to connect directly to `/var/www/wallinphotography.net/public_html` and also be able to create, edit and delete files within that folder.

Comment: Updated the post to be more descriptive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/setting-up-vsftpd-tls-on-debian-8-jessie/

```
:/# mkdir /var/www/trinityplay.net/public_html
:/# adduser --home /var/www/trinityplay.net/public_html trinity
```

same pattern for other users and their home directories

check your permissions with

```
:/# ls -ld /var/www/trinityplay.net/public_html
```

if you get a 500 vsftp error you may need to 
add the following line in /etc/vsftp.conf

```
ftp_username=whatever-ftp-username
```

http://www.unix.com/ubuntu/71798-500-oops-vsftpd-cannot-locate-user-specified-ftp_username-ftp.html

Comment: Hi, that was pretty much what I did in the end! I did however work out another way of organizing the folders & users. Let's say I have a customer who has 2 websites on my server, then I made a folder for his FTP username and in that folder I put the websites' folders. Example: `/var/www/trinity/trinityplay.net` and `/var/www/trinity/trinityliferpg.com`. Might be useful for anyone reading this and wanting a organized FTP! :)

Comment: Also; to make the content editable in FTP; I did `sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/trinity`